# Different values returned by ulimit -r

Tags: linux, security, real-time, account, limits

I added to my system-wide /etc/security/limits.conf the following two rows:

```
*       soft    rtprio      55
*       hard    rtprio      55
```

After a system reboot, I get two different results according to the way I access my user account on the machine.

```
user@client# ssh user@server

user@server# ulimit -r
55
```

Then I logout and login again as root

```
user@client# ssh root@server

root@server# su - user
user@server# ulimit -r
0
```

I have no special settings neither in .bashrc nor in any other places, or, at least, I think so.

Why is this happening?

Comment: I think root has no such limitation and after `su - user` it inherits that value.

Comment: Apparently, su - <user> gives <user> the environment limits setup of the calling bash. Since root is the only user which must be explicitly described in limits.conf for its limit values to be changed, becoming <user> from root gives always the wrong ulimit values.

What I tried was to set a row for root like

`root - rtprio 55`

and then the above commands gave the same result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must look at the PAM configuration of `ssh` and `su`. I suppose that they are not the same.

For example at my system:

```
$ grep limit /etc/pam.d/su
# Sets up user limits, please uncomment and read /etc/security/limits.conf
# (Replaces the use of /etc/limits in old login)
# session    required   pam_limits.so

$ grep limit /etc/pam.d/sshd
# access limits that are hard to express in sshd_config.
# Set up user limits from /etc/security/limits.conf.
session    required     pam_limits.so
```

As you can see in one of the cases the `pam_limits` line is commented. I suppose that you have something like this also.

Comment: You were right: I fixed it and now it works as expected, thanks!