# How to setup jackd and guitarix with real-time priority under Raspbian?

Tags: linux, embedded, low-latency, ulimit, jack

I am trying to get guitarix and jack running on the Raspberry Pi 2 (+ Cirrus audio card) with raspbian.
When starting jack via qjackctl, I get the errors

```
Cannot lock down 82278944 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory)
Cannot use real-time scheduling (RR/10)(1: Operation not permitted)
```

It seems changes to */etc/security/limits.conf* do not apply but to */etc/security/limits.d/audio.conf* do.

I tried setting the memory lock size for the user and group:

```
@audio - rtprio 90          # maximum realtime priority
@audio - memlock unlimited  # maximum locked-in-memory address space (KB)
@audio - nice -10
pi      - rtprio 90
pi      - memlock unlimited
pi      - nice -10
```

From ssh I get a satisfactory result:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 30
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 7349
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 90
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 7349
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

But from the desktop terminal I access via vnc I get

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 7349
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 7349
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

How can the same user have different settings and how do I get rt and memory allocation running on the desktop?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to have been a problem with the PAM configuration as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11295731/2451992).

Uncommenting the line in */etc/pam.d/su* did the trick.

```
# session    required   pam_limits.so
```